# how to delete outgoing voicemail in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I accidentally left a 5 minute outgoing voicemail after making a Teams voice call that wasn't answered.  How can I delete this ?

I searched all Microsoft support sites, but I'm unable to find anything on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You left this voicemail to another user’s account?

Comment: @Ramhound, yes. Basically it was the equivalent of a cellphone butt call :-)

Comment: Yeah; You can’t if your not the owner of the account you called

Comment: ok. They should have a "recall message" or something, especially if you realize it within a minute or two